# The proper way to restyle a core paper element globally in Polymer

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0, shadow-dom

The easy answer is, just include

```
paper-button{
 background: black;
}
```

, but that wouldn't restyle the element if it is contained in another element. The solution used to be

```
html /deep/ paper-button{
 background: black;
}
```

which still works fine, but is deprecated from the Shadow DOM spec. So what is the proper solution?

---

PS. Purely to be complete in case it somehow matters: What I actually want to reproduce properly is

```
html /deep/ paper-button.main{
 [...]
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding !important; to that style?

Comment: @LorDex To what style? The first style isn't supposed to select into the Shadow DOM and the second style already works but is going to be removed from browsers so it's pointless to add `!important` to that one... So I have no idea about which style you're talking right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS custom properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling-details) to change the `paper-button` style globally.

Since `paper-button` exposes the `--paper-button` *mixin*, you can try the following inside your document -

```
<style is="custom-style">
  simple-dialog, paper-button {
    --paper-button: {
      background-color: black; 
      color: white;
    };
  }
</style>
```

Have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oLd95cSdETmlv7RG9CNz?p=preview).

Comment: So lets say we have a third party `simple-dialog` element which uses a `paper-button`, how do you suggest now that we inject this shared style into this `simple-dialog`? Or should every element out there start adding `<style include="shared-styles"></style>`?

Comment: Actually my previous solution was about setting styles externally, which wasn't the best way to address this issue. Please have a look at my updated answer.